# Is it fine if an external program edit the sudoers file?

Tags: linux, sudo, environment-variables

My program needs some local environment variables while running as root to perform certain tasks. Would it be fine to write a subroutine that can change users sudoers to keep these variables? It's not only going to run on my personal computer, it will run on many users computers. The environment variables I need are mainly DESKTOP_SESSION or any of its variants and QT_X11_NO_MITSHM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a subroutine that modifies system files (`/etc/sudoers` or any other really) whenever your program runs is a bad design idea.

The more graceful  solution is that when you build and package your program for specific Linux distributions, such as for instance RHEL/CentOS 6 & 7, Ubuntu 16 & 18, you make use of and install a drop in configuration snippet in `/etc/sudoers.d/program-name` that will ensure that the specific sudo settings you need (such as protecting specific environment variables) are applied whenever your program runs.

Comment: Woah that's awesome! Didn't know we could do that. Might you know an example for debian based distros like ubuntu?

Comment: The drop-in file can contain all the same directives you would set in `/etc/sudoers` so if you were thinking of  something along the lines of `env_keep += "DESKTOP_SESSION QT_X11_NO_MITSHM"` simple create a file with that a line like that.

Comment: So basically I need to create a file with name of the program under /etc/sudoers.d/ with the line env_keep += "DESKTOP_SESSION QT_X11_NO_MITSHM. Executing the program again with sudo will allow it access to the variables?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It wasn't working earlier but I added a tab space after prepending Defaults and it worked! What I did `Defaults    env_keep += "DESKTOP_SESSION"`